# vsts How do I add columns to task boards

Tags: azure-devops

I have looked at various articles and can see how to add columns to story boards, however we are working in sprints using the task boards and I cannot find any way of adding another column to the task board. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin for your project. Click the "Process" that you're currently using. Find "Task" in the "Work Item Types" tab. Click the "States" tab and add a new State. This new state will appear as a column on the task board.

Comment: Thank you, I have now discovered that I cannot do any of this because I am using an om premises version.

Comment: We have no changned the project to use a customised process and are now able to update the states. Thank you for your help.